# Catch all type exceptions programming Android

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm developing an application for Android OS.
Since this is my first application, I think I've committed some programming mistakes cause I hardly can trace bugs back to their causes.
Thus, I was guessing, while i'm trying to fix bugs, is there a way to catch ALL types of exception in my entire activity lifecycle with one try-catch?

That would be awesome, i'm getting bored watching my galaxy S say :"Sorry the application App has stopped unexpectly" :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I really, really don't recommend this...

```
try {
     ...
} catch (Exception e) {
     // This will catch any exception, because they are all descended from Exception
}
```

Are you looking at your stack traces to debug your issues? It should not be hard to track them down. Look at LogCat and review the big block of red text to see which method caused your crash and what your error was.

If you catch all your errors this way, your program is not going to behave as expected, and you will not get error reports from Android Market when your users report them.

You can use an UncaughtExceptionHandler to possibly prevent some crashes. I use one, but only to print stack traces to a file, for when I'm debugging an app on a phone away from my computer. But I pass on the uncaught exception to the default Android UncaughtExceptionHandler after I've done that, because I want Android to be able to handle it correctly, and give the user the opportunity to send me a stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, you surely right not recommending that, but i wanted to know if I had the opportunity to handle all the Uncaught Exception and notify the user with one custom-activity (still, using UncaughtExceptionHandler, it doesn't launch correctly the new Activity).Anyway, I saw the Logcat tab in the Debug perspective, but i have never looked at it, Thank you all for the tip! P.S. How do you implement the passage between your UncaughtExceptionHandler and the AndroidUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Comment: In the constructor, put mDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();  Then in uncaughtException(...) call mDefaultUEH.uncaughtException() at the end of the method.

Comment: It doesn't catch "OutOfMemoryError" exception.

Comment: If you want to prevent your app from crashing at all, then you need to catch all `Throwable` like in MJB's answer. You can't catch `OutOfMemoryError` because it is not an exception, it is another class that inherits `Throwable`

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming like pure java

```
try {

} catch(throwable t) {

}
```

But this is Very Bad Practice.

Also look at

[Setting UncaughtException handler](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/setUncaughtExceptionHandler.htm)

Comment: Yes, I think what the OP is looking for is the UncaughtExceptionHandler. You can set it to NOT blow up and show the "Force close" message, but normally you still want to let it finish, since you probably can't recover.

Comment: Yeah, the UncaughtExceptionhandler is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Eclipse, every exception that Force-Closes the app (aka the message you mention) should be logged in the "LogCat".

The easiest way to see the LogCat, is to Open the DDMS perspective and clic on the LogCat tab (or open it from the "View" menu if it's not already displayed).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class SRSDexception implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

private Activity app = null;

public SRSDexception(Activity app) {
this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    this.app = app;

}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) 
{   

StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
String Raghav =t.toString();
String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n"+Raghav;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
}
report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

// If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
// AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
Throwable cause = e.getCause();
if(cause != null) {
report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
arr = cause.getStackTrace();
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
}
}
report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

try {
FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput(
"stack.trace", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
trace.write(report.getBytes());
trace.close();
} catch(IOException ioe) {
// ...
}

defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
}

}
```