# Android Out of Memory Events

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

Is there any way to get statistics about Out of Memory events that occurred, even
if its only how many ?

Primarily I am concerned with the count of events and when they occurred. It is
needed in an app I am building.

Is there some API support or do I need to parse some file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) it's free and easy to setup.It automatically sends you crash report, without prompting anything to the user, with full stack trace and statistics about the phone (even without internet connection).

Or something like that which will catch everything :

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class SRSDexception implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
private Activity app = null;

public SRSDexception(Activity app) {

this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
this.app = app;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) 
{   

StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
String Raghav =t.toString();
String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n"+Raghav;

for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
}
report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

// If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
// AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
Throwable cause = e.getCause();
if(cause != null) {
report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
arr = cause.getStackTrace();
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
}
}
report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

try {
FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput(
"stack.trace", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
trace.write(report.getBytes());
trace.close();
} catch(IOException ioe) {
// ...
}

defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
}

}
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773993/catch-all-type-exceptions-programming-android).

Comment: Primarily I am concerned with the number of events and when they occurred. Is there any way I can do that on my own ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the OOM error in development environment then you can use Logcat to see GC messages and maybe log events in your app. There are also many tools available from DDMS Eclipse view to help you track allocations and see exactly which objects are taking up memory.

There are a ton of information available on [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html).

Comment: Thanks for you response. I need the count of OOM errors of all apps to be read into my app and this is needed in production. This is what I am asking.

Comment: You want analytics information sent from end users such as # of times user did something ?

Comment: I want to know if there is a place or a way to access/calculate information regarding the number of times an outOfMemoryError occurs in Android. i need this information in my app.